# Basic Help Needed in Coding Data Using Stata

Tags: stata, missing-data

```
id  Year  Lat  Long 
 1  1990   10    11
 3  1994    2     8
 .  1998    2     8
 1  1993    .     .
 1  1991   10     .
 3  1996    .     8
```

I recently started working with Stata and I am having some difficulty coding my data. Attached above is a sample of what the data looks like. The idea is that I have a time series of objects with known latitudes and longitudes. The data, however, has some missing values. For example, in the 3rd row the id should be 3 because the latitude and longitude are the same as row 2. Also, in row 4, the latitude and longitude should be 10 and 11 respectively because the id is the same as in row 1. How will I go about coding this? Is there a simple command in Stata that can solve this issue? My understanding of Stata is fairly basic because I have just started using it.

Edit: It should look like this in finalized form:

```
id  Year  Lat  Long
 1  1990   10    11
 3  1994    2     8
 3  1998    2     8
 1  1993   10    11
 1  1991   10    11
 3  1996    2     8
```

Comment: Even if just starting with new software, you should be prepared to answer: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) A more informative title is also recommended.

Comment: It will help to add what you have tried. But this is probably enough to be migrated now.

Comment: So how do I transfer it? thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://www.sealedenvelope.com/stata/xfill/

Other ways here: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/

Or `carryforward` from SSC.